# Debian dependencies vs Python dependencies in Python project

Tags: package-management, software-installation, python, dependencies, deb

I have a project named `myapp` written in python, and I'm creating it using setuptools, with the corresponding setup file at `myapp/setup.py`, where all the dependencies of my project are specified. Then, I'm creating a debian package `myapp.deb` that contains the whole python project, and its only dependency is `python-setuptools`. The problem is that I'm not sure who should handle my project's dependencies. For now, it goes like this

1. when I run `apt-get install myapp`, it copies the python code to `/var/lib/myapp` and installs the `python-setuptools` dependency.
2. the postinst script of the `myapp.deb` package calls `python /var/lib/myapp/setup.py install`, installing `myapp` with setuptools, which fetches all the dependencies that I specified in the `setup.py` file.

So, my questions are:

- Is this fine, to let python's setuptools handle the dependencies?
- Should I remove the dependencies from `myapp/setup.py` and add the corresponding debian packages as dependencies of the outter `myapp.deb` package? In this case, setuptools would install `myapp`, but not fetch any dependency, which should already have been retrieved with `apt-get install myapp`. But in that case, I need those dependencies also to run the unit tests of myapp when I call `python myapp/setup.py test`. How do I handle the test dependencies?
- Should I completely rely on apt, remove `setup.py`, and not use setuptools at all? In that case, how would I run my unit tests, with the proper dependencies set?

Comment: See https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/